# Saving a image that was converted into byte[] without System.Drawing?

Tags: c#, image, imaging

Yes you can just use:

```
// A byte array that contains a .jpeg data.
System.IO.Stream BitmapStream = System.IO.MemoryStream(byteBuffer);
System.Drawing.Bitmap MyImage = System.Drawing.Bitmap.FromStream(BitmapStream);
MyImage.Save("C:\Folder\Folder\image.jpeg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

But how could you do this without `System.Drawing`?

I would like to write my own code to create the image.

Comment: You would need to find another way of converting the Bitmap to a Jpeg.  This would require another library (unless you want to write your own). The main work being done here by System.Drawing is conversion from BMP to JPEG

Comment: Are you asking "converting a bitmap to jpeg without System.Drawing"?

Comment: I'm asking how to save an image that was converted into a byte[], without using `System.Drawing`.

Comment: There is no "converted into byte[]" - what is the *format* of the data? If the byte array contains JPEG data already, just save the byte array. No need to get GDI+ involved.

Comment: The data is read by `System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes();` Thank you for your help.

Comment: Luaan is saying that you need to know the format of the file you are reading in.  The image data can be stored in many different formats, bitmap, jpeg, png.  All of these use a different encoding for the image.  For example if you change the file extension of a bmp file to jpg it will not load properly.  To change from one format to another will require conversion.  System.Drawing does this for you when you call save passing in the required format as the second parameter.

Comment: Ahh okay so `.jpeg`.

Comment: Then your accepted answer will work.  No conversion required.  No need for the System.Drawing namespace at all. Just save the bytes.

Comment: That's what I have done, and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the image in bytes you don't need to use drawing to make an image, just save it as a binary file.

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("C:\Folder\Folder\image.png", byteBuffer);
```